# Pyinstaller with cv2 (opencv) OS app does not work as expected

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm successfully using Pyinstaller to create a distributable for my pyqt5 application using opencv. When I run the console-based executable from the dist folder, everyting works fine. However, when I execute the .app file of my application, upon pressing the button which triggers `import cv2` , the application crashes with `seg fault 11`; meaning cannot import cv2.

How is this possible? I have tried

```
import cv2
cv2.__file__
```

And use this output to `--paths` option of Pyinstaller with no success.

Comment: Did you build cv2 (opencv) from source?

Comment: I tried building from source, pip installing, everything